# PayPal REST API - Sandbox returning 401 for API requests but successful access token

Tags: rest, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am using the PayPal REST API in Java to make a request to the testing (sandbox) servers for an access token, which succeeds, and then sending that access token back to the same sandbox servers for a Payment which fails with a 401 Not Authorized.

I followed the PayPal REST API instructions found here: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#authentication--headers and here https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/direct/make-your-first-call/

I tried using the `OAuthTokenCredential` object to provide my `clientId` and `clientSecret` but it only returns me the access token, not the `appID` provided by PayPal nor the `expiresIn` time in minutes.  In addition, it complains about a missing `sdk_conf.properties` file in my classpath.

I then created my own class to make the call using Apache's HttpClient to get the full response and that works:

### Custom PayPalAPI interface for RestEasy

```java
@Path("v1/oauth2/token")
public interface PayPalOAuthAPI {
    @POST
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
    public OAuthInfo requestAccessToken(
        @HeaderParam("Authorization") String basicEncodedToken, 
        String requestBody
    );
}
```

### Custom OAuth token request

```java
private OAuthInfo getOAuthInfo() {
    OAuthInfo info = null;

    PayPalOAuthAPI client = HttpClientFactory.createRestEasyClient(80, 443, 120, 2,
                                          API_ENDPOINT, PayPalOAuthAPI.class, true);
    info = client.requestAccessToken("Basic "+
                                    generateBase64String(PP_API_USER, PP_API_SECRET),
                                    "grant_type=client_credentials");

    if (info == null) {
        throw new RuntimeException(APIResultCodes.REMOTE_UNAUTHORIZED, 
                                   "Could not authenticate with PayPal.");
    }
    return info;
}
```

This all works correctly and returns me a 200 OK status with the expected JSON response including an access token.

I then take that token and provide it to my `Payment` object which uses PayPal's code to communicate with their servers (under the hood I believe it's basic java.lang.net.HttpConnection code) and that returns a 401 Unauthorized.

### Payment call using PayPal's REST API

```java
// get a new token
String accessToken = getOAuthInfo().getAccessToken();

// configProps is a Properties object pre-populated with sdk_conf.properties
// values except service.EndPoint, clientID, and clientSecret
configProps.setProperty("service.EndPoint", API_ENDPOINT);

// ... transaction objects omitted

try {
    Payment payment = new Payment();
    Payment.initConfig(configProps);
    payment.setIntent(Intent.sale.toString());
    payment.setPayer(payer);
    payment.setTransactions(transactions);

    Payment createdPayment = payment.create(accessToken);
} catch (PayPalRESTException ex) {
    LOG.error("Failed to submit donation", ex);
}
```

### Log output

(including HttpClient request/response with IDs redacted)

```
2013-08-19 16:34:11,077 [qtp1005310362-44] DEBUG:org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection Sending request: POST /v1/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
2013-08-19 16:34:11,077 [qtp1005310362-44] DEBUG:org.apache.http.wire >> "POST /v1/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
2013-08-19 16:34:11,077 [qtp1005310362-44] DEBUG:org.apache.http.wire >> "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded[\r][\n]"
2013-08-19 16:34:11,077 [qtp1005310362-44] DEBUG:org.apache.http.wire >> "Accept: application/json[\r][\n]"
2013-08-19 16:34:11,077 [qtp1005310362-44] DEBUG:org.apache.http.wire >> "Authorization: Basic QWM1UmNoQ3g3dHB1bWZSZW9rcUR3MW41bHRXaktQU0xRODIyWUJWWXpEdXpZUGJuc0J0eDZYWGlqX1pROkVJVnQ5eERmM2JnQmw1OG5KYlZ2VmtSR3JCaVZVN1BIWGtSV01mQjVqb3NxRTNkbWxCcF9TV05BdU91eA==[\r][\n]"
2013-08-19 16:34:11,077 [qtp1005310362-44] DEBUG:org.apache.http.wire >> "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate[\r][\n]"
2013-08-19 16:34:11,077 [qtp1005310362-44] DEBUG:org.apache.http.wire >> "Content-Length: 29[\r][\n]"
2013-08-19 16:34:11,077 [qtp1005310362-44] DEBUG:org.apache.http.wire >> "Host: api.sandbox.paypal.com[\r][\n]"
2013-08-19 16:34:11,077 [qtp1005310362-44] DEBUG:org.apache.http.wire >> "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
2013-08-19 16:34:11,077 [qtp1005310362-44] DEBUG:org.apache.http.wire >> "User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.2 (java 1.5)[\r][\n]"
2013-08-19 16:34:11,078 [qtp1005310362-44] DEBUG:org.apache.http.wire >> "[\r][\n]"
2013-08-19 16:34:11,078 [qtp1005310362-44] DEBUG:org.apache.http.wire >> "grant_type=client_credentials"
2013-08-19 16:34:12,690 [qtp1005310362-44] DEBUG:org.apache.http.wire << "HTTP/1.1 200 OK[\r][\n]"
2013-08-19 16:34:12,690 [qtp1005310362-44] DEBUG:org.apache.http.wire << "Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1[\r][\n]"
2013-08-19 16:34:12,690 [qtp1005310362-44] DEBUG:org.apache.http.wire << "Date: Mon, 19 Aug 2013 20:34:11 GMT[\r][\n]"
2013-08-19 16:34:12,690 [qtp1005310362-44] DEBUG:org.apache.http.wire << "PayPal-Debug-Id: d29c41eb8625a[\r][\n]"
2013-08-19 16:34:12,690 [qtp1005310362-44] DEBUG:org.apache.http.wire << "Content-Type: application/json[\r][\n]"
2013-08-19 16:34:12,690 [qtp1005310362-44] DEBUG:org.apache.http.wire << "Content-Length: 282[\r][\n]"
2013-08-19 16:34:12,690 [qtp1005310362-44] DEBUG:org.apache.http.wire << "[\r][\n]"
2013-08-19 16:34:12,690 [qtp1005310362-44]     2013-08-19 16:34:12,691 [qtp1005310362-44] DEBUG:org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient Connection can be kept alive indefinitely
2013-08-19 16:34:12,691 [qtp1005310362-44] DEBUG:org.apache.http.wire << "{"scope":"https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/.* https://api.paypal.com/v1/vault/credit-card https://api.paypal.com/v1/vault/credit-card/.* openid","access_token":"RVATuLOQB0WFX
    keSDZQw4ZnyfIduPCF2j7sMhcfspwo","token_type":"Bearer","app_id":"APP-80W284285Q519543T","expires_in":28800}"
2013-08-19 16:34:12,693 [qtp1005310362-44] DEBUG:org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingClientConnectionManager Connection [id: 5][route: {s}->https://api.sandbox.paypal.com] can be kept alive indefinitely
2013-08-19 16:34:12,693 [qtp1005310362-44] DEBUG:org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingClientConnectionManager Connection released: [id: 5][route: {s}->https://api.sandbox.paypal.com][total kept alive: 1; route allocated: 1 of 2; total allocated: 1 of 2]
2013-08-19 16:34:15,197 [qtp1005310362-44] ERROR:com.example.gateways.paypal.payments.PayPalPaymentsProREST Failed to submit donation
    com.paypal.core.rest.PayPalRESTException: Error code : 401 with response : Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment
```

I noticed the scope and the URL the API sent me to are two different things.  Perhaps I'm missing some configuration to sent the API calls to the sandbox URL?

In my code above you can see I'm setting the `service.EndPoint` to `API_ENDPOINT` which is set to the `https://api.sandbox.paypal.com` in my tests.  I am also not providing the `clientID` or `clientSecret` in my properties object, but even providing them gives me a 401.

What else am I missing?

Comment: Same problem here. Any solution found?

Comment: No official solution.  I switched back to using the official OAuthTokenCredentials object and that worked (but I have no access to the APP_ID or expires_in time.  Then I changed back to my own OAuthUtil object and it started working to make a donation.  However, every donation failed with either a 500 error, timeout, or returned null.  I'm now experimenting with the Classic API.

Answer (score 0):

Came across this question and had a similar problem when trying to make payments for a third party PayPal account.

Not sure if you're running into the same thing I was, but I was trying to create payments for a third party paypal account to which I had not properly requested permission. Turns out I needed to use the Permissions API to request proper permissions.

See this link: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/permissions-service/integration-guide/PermissionsAbout/

Comment: This looks like PayPal's Classic API. Were you using this with the REST API?

Comment: I actually flip flopped a bit here. Turns out you can't mix Classic and REST, so you can't create a rest API application that acts on behalf of another account (which relies on the classic permissions api). The main point to take away here is that if you're trying to use the REST api to make a request on behalf of someone else, you can fetch an access token, but you'll receive a 401 when trying to create a payment.

Comment: Correct. As far as I can tell, the REST API doesn't let you make requests on behalf of another user, even if you do the full OAUTH Delegation Process. You have to use the Classic API's to make requests for another party. And as you noted, the Application domains for REST and Classic are different, and require a separate verification process.